# How to specify user/password for MongoDB erlang driver?

Tags: mongodb, erlang, mlab

This driver is used: https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-erlang

I was not able to connect to my mongodb (mongolab) because I cannot set my username:password
I've tried username:pass@mongoserver but that crushes the application.

When I don't set anything it says that I have no permissions for write.

UPD 1:

So here are new errors

`main(_) ->
    application:start (bson),
    application:start (mongodb),

```
Host = {"myname.mongolab.com", 53798},

{ok, Connection} = mongo:connect(Host),

ok = mongo:do(safe, master, Connection, micomico, fun() ->
           mongo:auth(<<"micomico">>,<<"password">>),
           mongo:insert (teams, {x,1, y,2})
    end).
```

`

and the result is:

`exception error: no match of right hand side value {failure,
                                                    {write_failure,16544,
                                                     <<"not authorized for insert on micomico.teams">>}}`

UPD2
Finally I was able to do queries with mentioned code.

Comment: Please post your Erlang code and the error message from MongoDB.

Comment: Actually there are no errors =) I just don't know the way to specify login/password. Looks like there is no way to do that out of the box. Another driver called erlmongo doesn't support the authentication too and author said that he has no plans for this.

Comment: I checked MongoDB-Erlang driver API, it looks there is no way to set the credentials. Really strange! But I'm might be missing something.

Comment: Checkout to master branch. There is mongo:auth/2 function.

Comment: If you want to use refactor branch, you can implement auth method with mongo:find/2-4 and mongo:command/1 functions. Read [mongo wire protocol auth docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/implement-authentication-in-driver/).

Comment: I was not able to compile the master branch: `==> bson (get-deps)
==> mongodb-erlang (get-deps)
==> bson (compile)
==> mongodb-erlang (compile)
src/mongo.erl:394: syntax error before: '.'
src/mongo.erl:34: function add_user/3 undefined
src/mongo.erl:391: spec for undefined function mongo:add_user/3
src/mongo.erl:380: Warning: crypto:md5/1 is deprecated and will be removed in in a future release; use crypto:hash/2
src/mongo.erl:383: Warning: crypto:md5/1 is deprecated and will be removed in in a future release; use crypto:hash/2
make: *** [compile] Error 1`

Comment: After removing add_user specific code from mongo.erl it is compiled now =)

Comment: Please look for updated note under UPD 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/mongodb-erlang - this fork of mongodb-erlang driver provides `mongo:auth` and `mongo:add_user` functions.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for this link. I've cloned this rep but I cannot find any 'auth' in it's sources. But yes, docs say that they exist.

Comment: It becomes very interesting =) In this commit I can see the auth code https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/mongodb-erlang/commit/fe00618a18f16de9ee8bfe8b4eeb4deb1d12f267 but IDK why it was dropped =)

Comment: Ha, looks like this commit was total mongo.erl rewrite with dropping the good functionality! https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/mongodb-erlang/commit/47ddb648668faa021da00d8cb116244acf43c4fe